# How can I assign values in pairs?

Tags: java

I want to assign values and make it as a pair.

For example `OrderID` and `ItemID`

Items are in list. What should I use to look like this `(OrderID,ItemID)` where `OrderID` should be the same for all `ItemID` in list.

All examples and samples are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you should probably create a class ```Order``` with members ```orderId``` and ```itemId```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multimap could be a good construct: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

```
Multimap<O, I> orders = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Replace O and I with the types for orders and items. The structure will hold an array list of Is for each O.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map and store key value-pairs if itemID is unique

 `Map<Long,Long> pairMap=new HashMap<Long,Long>();`
and to add things in it pairMap.put(ItemID,OrderID) .

Comment: Map is correct, but from orders to items, not like you suggest (see: "where `OrderID` should be the same for all ItemID in list"). Please correct.

Comment: Oops, I thought of something completely different and therefore no, your answer is not really good. I will post mine in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new object or you can store them in a little Object array.
If they have a more common ancestor from which they inherit you can instead make that type of array. You can also give one type of the two a field that holds the other (if you have a one to many relation between them for example). In your case you could consider giving orderID a field for itemID and storing the related item in there. It al depends on what you want to do with it though.